# Помогите разобраться с копированием списков в python

Tags: python

Немного запутался в копировании списков. Если рассматривать обычный список, то копирование через слайс выдает ожидаемый результат:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]

b.append(0)

print(a)  #[1, 2, 3]
print(b)  #[1, 2, 3, 0]
print(id(a))  #...8832
print(id(b))  #...8448
```

Со вложенными списками такая тема не прокатывает, только если использовать deepcopy

```
a = [[0]*3 for i in range(4)]
b = a[:]

b[0].append(2)

print(id(a) == id(b))  # False

print(a)   # [[0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print(b)   # [[0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Хотя как я понял имена ссылаются на разные объекты, что показывает функция id

Comment: Вы посмотрели id списков верхнего уровня. Они, естественно, разные (вы же использовали срез). Вы распечатайте id вложенных подсписков каждого из списка и увидите одинаковость.

Comment: `print(id(a[0]) == id(b[0]))`

Answer (score 2):

В списках объекты хранятся по ссылке. Вы копируете внешний список, и это действительно уже другой объект, как показывает функция id. Но эти разные (внешние) списки хранят в себе ссылки на одни и те же объекты вложенных списков. Поэтому, когда вы добавляете новый элемент в один из вложенных списков, вы видите это изменение и во втором внешнем списке т.к. он ссылается по сути на тот же объект.

Попробуйте сравнить объекты а[0] и b[0]