# Изменение списка с помощью цикла

Tags: python, list, циклы

За пример возьмем такой код:

```
sp = [1, [2], 3]
for i in sp:
    i *= 2
    print(i)
print(sp)
```

Результатом он даст:

```
2
[2, 2]
6
[1, [2, 2], 3]
```

Сам вопрос: Почему меняется элемент списка sp без прямого обращения, если значением этого элемента является список?

Итератор i лишь принимает значение очередного элемента списка sp, и при взаимодействии с ним значения элементов изначального списка меняться не должны, что мы и видим на примере чисел. Но, если элементом списка sp является подсписок, то картина совершенно иная.

Comment: таков синтаксис языка: умножение списка на целое число приводит к дублированию элементов списка. помедитируйте над выводом `$ python3 -c 'print(3 * [5, 6, 7])'`

Comment: По этой логике и значения чисел в первоначальном списке должны измениться. Александр, вопрос в другом: почему меняется значение элемента списка без прямого обращения.

Comment: изменяется потому, что `x *= y` — это синтаксический сахар вокруг оператора **присвоения** `x = x * y`. вот вам ещё пример для медитации: `$ python -c 'x=[1];y=x;y*=2;print(y)'`

Comment: У нас есть список sp. В нём есть три элемента: число, список, число. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на пример. С помощью цикла каждый элемент мы умножили на два с помощью *=. 

После цикла мы вывели на экран sp. И в списке изменилось значение только второго элемента, числа же остались нетронутыми. 

Итератор i — это отдельная переменная, которая лишь принимает значение элемента списка, но не обращается к элементу списка напрямую, поэтому и изменения изначального списка быть не должно.

Comment: [первый попавшийся дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1370196/178576). ну и другие подобные [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Благодарю. Фактически, любое упоминание списка даже для других переменных — это обращение к тому самому списку. 

Вопрос решён.

Comment: только обратил внимание, что опечатался в примере: выводить подразумевалось не `y`, а `x`: `$ python -c 'x=[1];y=x;y*=2;print(x)'`. впрочем, вывод будет ровно таким же, что и должно навести на размышления (о смысле жизни или о технической реализации списков в интерпретаторах python).

Comment: Итератор i - не итератор, итераторы должны реализовывать методы __iter__() and __next__().

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разберём ваш код.

Вы проходите список

```
sp = [1, [2], 3]
for i in sp:
    i *= 2
```

Прежде всего. Давайте сразу определимся, что существуют значимые и ссылочные типы данных.

Значимые (int, float, double, boolean и т.д.)

Ссылочные (разнообразные структуры данных, в том числе список, list)

Когда вы проходите список циклом for, в зависимости от того, на какой именно элемент в списке указывает указатель i он ведёт себя по разному.

В случае с числами, внутри цикла for i становится локальной (внутри цикла) копией числа, взятого из списка. Когда вы умножаете i, вы умножаете копию. Действительно, выводя её на экран изнутри цикла вы получите умноженное значение, но это не значение внутри списка, это копия.

В случае со списком внутри списка, i указывает на объект, и последующая операция умножения применяется к объекту, который, соответственно изменяется. В данном случае i - это не локальная копия, i - это указатель, на тот самый "подсписок"

Если вы хотите поэлементно умножить каждый элемент списка, обращайтесь к нему по индексу.

```
for i in range(len(sp)): 
    sp[i] *= 2
```

Успехов.

Comment: Спасибо! Как я понял, список занимает ячейку памяти и при обращении к изменяемому объекту используется именно ссылка на ячейку, но, как вы верно подметили, копия не создаётся.

Вот в том и проблема, что эффект нужен был ровно обратный. Требовалось провести некоторый анализ списка списков, но при этом его не менять. А в итоге выяснилось, что своими действиями я поменял значения изначального кода. 
Но у этой истории хэппи-энд, так что всё отлично. Со списками разобрался, задачи решил. 

Ещё раз спасибо вам, и удачи :)

Answer (score 1):

Тут на самом деле есть две тонкости:

1. **Разница между переменными-значениями и ссылочными переменными.** Это один из первых вопросов на любом собеседовании для программистов - объяснить, в чём между ними разница. Так вот и в данном случае когда вы проходите по списку, то в переменной цикла у вас получаются объекты (а в питоне всё является объектами), которые ведут себя несколько по-разному. Числа являются переменными-значениями, а переменнные-значения *иммутабельны*, то есть если число каким-то образом меняется, то оно уже никак не может содержаться в том же объекте, в переменную будет положено новое число, содержащееся в другом объекте. А вот списки могут быть модифицированы "на месте". Это может быть уже другой по сути объект, с другим содержимым, но физически это будет всё ещё старый объект списка, с тем же адресом памяти.

Давайте добавим в ваш код печать адреса переменной `i` до изменения и после изменения:

```
sp = [1, [2], 3]
for i in sp:
    id1 = id(i)
    i *= 2
    id2 = id(i)
    print(id1, '==' if id1 == id2 else "!=", id2, i)
print(sp)
```

Вывод:

```
139686891790624 != 139686891790656 2
139686765180672 == 139686765180672 [2, 2]
139686891790688 != 139686891790784 6
[1, [2, 2], 3]
```

Видите? Адрес числовых переменных меняется - теперь это новые объекты, не имеющие больше связи с теми объектами, которые были в списке. А вот список, вложенный в список, сохранил свою идентичность - это тот же самый объект, но уже изменённый.

2. **Есть некоторая разница между оператором, используемым в разных формах.**

В "полной форме":

```
переменная = переменная оператор значение
```

В "сокращённой" форме:

```
переменная оператор= значение
```

Давайте поменяем в вашем коде `i *= 2` на `i = i * 2`, что же будет на выходе тогда:

```
139686891790624 != 139686891790656 2
139686546719168 != 139686526698432 [2, 2]
139686891790688 != 139686891790784 6
[1, [2], 3]
```

В данном случае операция со списком не выполнилась "по месту", а был создан новый список, ссылка на который присвоилась в переменную `i`, и этот список потерял связь с нашим списком! Так что эти два оператора `= *` и `*=` оказались не совсем тождественными, об этом нужно помнить.

Comment: Благодарю! Только в самом начале пути и пока не претендую даже на звание джуна. Но всё придёт с опытом :)